# Finding peak-to-peak values in time intervals MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have data organized into 2 matrices, 'time' and 'data'. I want to find the peak-to-peak values of the first column of the 'data' matrix. I am attempting to do this by going through the data points, 500 points at a time, and finding the max and min values within each interval. The peak is found by adding the absolute values of both values to one another.

peak=abs(maxV)+abs(minV)

These values are then saved to an excel spreadsheet (if they are larger than 1500) where they can be looked at afterwards. However, the data matrix has around 1798824 rows and this process is very tedious.

Is there a better way to write this code to speed up the process? And do the loops look ok? I have tried to find a way to go straight to the next iteration if the 'if' condition is not met, but I am not sure how to do this in MATLAB.

```
%maxV=maximum thrust value
%minV=minimum thrust value
%maxI=index of maximum thrust
%minI=index of minimum thrust
%peakV=peak thrust value
%peakT=time at which peak thrust value occurred

d=dir('*');%Creates matrix d which contains all the file names in the folder.
d=d(~[d.isdir]);% removes folders from the list (if some exist)
d={d.name}.';%removes the locations of the files, leaving only the names.
nf=numel(d);%calculates the variables in d
j=zeros([1,15]); %creates starting matrix to which the peak result, indexes and values can be added to

for i=3:nf


[time,data,sensors]=IMO_read_time(d{i},1); %executes function that reads binary and gives data in 3 matrices(time,data,sensors)

nrows=size(data,1); %number of data rows in matrix A
peakvalues=round((nrows/500)); %number of peak results for sampling frequency of 500Hz

for p=1:peakvalues %range of possible peak results
    for n=1:500:nrows %number of data points to be read(interval of 500)
        k=n+499;      %stating end value to be read in each interval
        if k<=nrows   %end value must be smaller than number of rows in data

        [maxV maxI]=max(data(n:k,1)); %finds maxV and maxI within 500 data points
        [minV minI]=min(data(n:k,1)); %finds maxV and maxI within 500 data points

        maxT=time(maxI,1); %finds time of maximum value
        minT=time(minI,1); %finds time of minimum value

        peakV=abs(maxV)+abs(minV); %finds peak to peak between maxV and minV

        if peakV>1500 


    Real_maxT=datevec(datenum(1970,1,1)+(maxT/86400)); %converts UNIX time into UPS format
    Real_minT=datevec(datenum(1970,1,1)+(minT/86400)); %converts UNIX time into UPS format


    M=[peakV maxI minI Real_maxT Real_minT]; %creates matrix M with values of interest
    format long

    Newj=[j; M]; %adds M onto matrix j to create matrix Newj
    j=Newj; %j then becomes Newj for next iteration

    ind=find(j(:,1),1,'last'); %gives the index of the last value of matrix j
    p=sprintf('A%d',ind); %gives the row number that the data will be written to in excel      spreadsheet
    xlswrite('20131221_PeakValues_trial1', M, 1, p); %saves matrix M in excel spreadsheet, sheet1, row n

        end;

        end;

    end
end
```

end

Comment: If you have the toolbox for it, `findpeaks` may be of use to you.

Comment: Thank you for answering but unfortunately I don't have the toolbox. Maybe I will have to get it for this.

Comment: General notes; you are growing `j` in the loop, you don't need `newJ`, and if you're storing everything in `j` anyway, put the `xlswrite` outside the loop so you don't have to keep figuring out where to write the new data.  More specifics would depend on the shape of your peaks.

Comment: I don't see any problems or easy ways to improve speed. You might want to calculate the peak with `peakV = maxV - minV` to allow for the possibility that `maxV` is negative or `minV` is positive. It's an interesting problem, I'll think about it some more

Comment: As @nkjt said, move `xlswrite` ouside the loop if at all possible. xlswrite is a **very** slow function, it can take half a second for each call.

Comment: Try this function from the matlab file exchange:  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25500-peakfinder

Answer (score 1):

Removing the loops result in this code block:

```
nrows=size(data,1); %number of data rows in matrix A
peakvalues=round((nrows/500)); %number of peak results for sampling frequency of 500Hz

dataBlocks = reshape(data(1:500*peakvalues),500,peakvalues);

[maxV,maxIdx] = max(dataBlocks);
[minV,minIdx] = min(dataBlocks);
peakV = abs(maxV) + abs(minV);

maxT = time(maxIdx + ((1:peakvalues)-1)*500,1);
minT = time(minIdx + ((1:peakvalues)-1)*500,1);

interestingIdx = (peakV>1500);

upsMaxT = datevec(datenum(1970,1,1)+(maxT(interestingIdx)/86400)); %converts UNIX time into UPS format
upsMinT = datevec(datenum(1970,1,1)+(minT(interestingIdx)/86400)); %converts UNIX time into UPS format

M = [peakV(interestingIdx)' maxIdx(interestingIdx)' minIdx(interestingIdx)' upsMaxT upsMinT];

xlswrite('20131221_PeakValues_trial1', M, 1);
```

Additional note: You are looping over a `p`, but I dont see why that is done. Secondly, you assign a string value to this `p` later **inside** the loop.

---

**Edit**: I did not consider your first loop, but this one is not removed easily since it loops over files that are to be read.

Comment: this code looks a lot neater than mine, thanks! The only thing is that it wasn't faster because the xls write is still taking place.

Comment: I just realised: you can reduce the calls to xlswrite by writing the complete M at once, so I updated the code. That should actually speed up a lot.

Comment: I tried the new version of code and it is a lot faster but I had to adjust the maxT and minT part, but the time I got in the end did not look correct.

Comment: could you explain what 

maxT = time0(maxIdx + ((1:peakvalues)-1)*500,1);

this part means? It says that the index exceed matrix dimensions

Comment: I guess this is caused by the `round` function - you shoud replace it with `floor` (which round towards zero and hence ignores the last block that is less than 500 elements). What the code snippet does, is translating the `maxIdx` to the correct time index to obtain `maxT`. Due to the reshape of `data`, we need to shift the index values for the time array (which is not reshaped) .